# Is this a legitimate method for making sure implicit type conversion does not happen

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this a legitimate method for making sure implicit type conversion does not happen?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void func(std::string s)
{
   std::cout << "Thanks for the string\n";
}
template<class T>
void func(T)=delete;

int main()
{
   func("test1");
// str.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
// str.cc:13:16: error: use of deleted function ‘void func(T) [with T = const char*]’
//     func("test1");
//     ^
//  str.cc:9:6: error: declared here
//  void func(T)=delete;
//       ^
//
   func(std::string("test2"));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks good to me.

It does the same thing to answers.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The question was "is this a legitimate method..." and this answer is "yes," which is a perfectly valid answer given the question.

Comment: @cdhowie: You are right, I don't know how I misread the question :) (For some reason I thought the question was *how can you block implicit conversions*)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - That *is* a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that method ensures that implicit conversions are disallowed. However, it also means that this property does not arise from the definition of of `void func(string)` alone. So, in order to clarify this to readers, you could make it more self-contained as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename U> using RequireExplicit = enable_if_t<is_same<T, U>>;

template <typename T, typename = RequireExplicit<T, string>>
void func(T){}
```

Comment: Adhere to the rule of the least shocking.  Doing this is pointless and weird.  It could only confuse readers and make them wonder if the author knew what they were doing.  I would seriously be asking myself WTF over this code if I saw it because it causes ambiguity errors unless there's a non-template overload to disambiguate.  It's also the wrong way to go about "specializing" a function template.  At the very best this 'documentation' is superfluous, more likely misleading.  Don't do it.

Comment: @CrazyEddie I agree that it is somewhat jarring. But it could be made a bit more palatable(edited). However, your point about the ambiguity errors seems like strong reason against this use.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't cause ambiguity if `func(string)` exists because that function will override this definition.  But either that function is right there for me to see or it's off somewhere else.  If it's right there then this documentation doesn't help.  If it's somewhere else and I don't know that then I'll be spending hours trying to figure out what the guy who wrote this 'overload' intended.